# Detecting whether or not 3 or 4 data values to write to console

Tags: c++, ifstream, pos

How would you code it for the compile to be able to tell whether or not there are like only 2 cities or 3 cities to process when using ifstream to write to the console with data from a text file? An example of how each line will look as such:

```
Denver <> Chicago StLouis
Miami <> NewYork
```

```
pos = line.find(" ",8);
if(pos == string::npos){
    ifile >> city1;
    ifile >> type;
    cout << "Type:" << type << endl;
    ifile >> city2;
    cout << "City2:" << city2 << endl;
}
else{
    ifile >> city1;
    cout << "City1:" << city1 <<endl;
    ifile >> type;
    cout << "Type:" << type << endl;
    ifile >> city2;
    cout << "City2:" << city2 << endl;
    ifile >> city3;
    cout << "City3:" << city3 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Read line by line until EOF? (and store info  in `vector`).

Comment: If your problem is how to know before reading the file how many variables to declare, like only city1 and city2 be sufficient or you need to go upto city50, then that is the wrong approach. You don't declare variables in such a situation but use a container to put everything in it or stream the data through your processing pipeline.

Comment: What about this: https://repl.it/repls/EasygoingNavyTelecommunications  Just read all of them into a vector?  Or do you really need to know if there are two or three?

Comment: If you do need to know if it is ONE or TWO destinations, test the stream after reading the second one: https://repl.it/repls/HorizontalItchyUsers

Comment: the methods using the stringstream worked! Thanks everyone for the help.